# domestic air condition needs restart for cool air

Tags: air-conditioning, cooling

I have a new domestic air condition 9000btu in my room. I have the settings cool and 23 degree temperature and I noticed that when I turned it on for the first time of the day, it doesn't blow cool air but only normal air. After a few minutes I turned it off and I turned it again on, and it blows cool air. This what I do everyday.

What the problem might be? Do air condition needs more time to cool the room?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When was this installed? Have you contacted the installer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom it was installed around 2 years ago but it was used only 2-3 days. I didn't contacted the installer because is not certified installer. I think if it's faulty air condition

Comment: We'll need more info (e.g. unit make and model, and possibly picture). And, you should still [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.